# Finding METAFONT sources of a specific character

Tags: fonts, sourcecode, metafont, computer-modern

I'm trying to find out the METAFONT source of percent (%) character, which is created by `\%` with TeX. I am using the Normal `CMR10` font. I am doing this, because I want a slightly modified version of nice dots of this character with the same width but with half of its height.

[image]

**Fig. 1: Comparing Percent, Zero, and the character I want (in red)**

I know that the whole package of CMR MF source is available from CTAN (and also locally from TeXLive):

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/mf

But I can not find out where is the actual source of `%`. As `%` is also a special character of TeX which comments out a line and thus there are many instances of it, It is really tedious to manually check 123 MF files of Computer Modern.

So, is there a way to debug metafonts and see the characters one by one when running MF for example `mf cmr10`? Or may be other reasonable ways to do this?

Comment: I strongly suggest reading [The METAFONTbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Typesetting) and [Computer Modern Typefaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Typesetting).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's follow what `cmr10.mf` says; at the end of it there is

```
generate roman
```

where `generate` is (usually) equivalent to `input`. Now `roman.mf` has

```
input romanu;  % upper case (majuscules)
input romanl;  % lower case (minuscules)
input greeku;  % upper case Greek letters
input romand;  % numerals
input romanp;  % ampersand, question marks, currency sign
input romspl;  % lowercase specials (dotless \i, ligature \ae, etc.)
input romspu;  % uppercase specials (\AE, \OE, \O)
input punct;  % punctuation symbols common to roman and italic text
input accent;  % accents common to roman and italic text
```

and we can try `punct.mf` where indeed we find

```
cmchar "Per cent sign";
beginchar("%",9u#+max(6u#,2fudge*(hair#+stem#)),
  body_height#,body_height#-asc_height#);
italcorr if hefty: .4asc_height#*slant-.5u# else: h#*slant-u# fi;
adjust_fit(0,0); pickup fine.nib;
numeric left_curve,right_curve;
left_curve=hround 5/6[fudged.hair,fudged.stem];
right_curve=max(fine.breadth,hround(fudged.hair if hefty:-2stem_corr fi));
pos1(vair,90); pos2(left_curve,180); pos3(vair,270); pos4(right_curve,360);
top y1r=h; lft x2r=hround u; rt x4r=hround(.5w-1.5u);
bot y3r=floor(if monospace: .7 else: .5 fi\\ asc_height);
x1=x3=.5[x2,x4]; y2=y4=.5[y1,y3];
filldraw stroke pulled_super_arc.e(1,2)(superpull)
 & pulled_super_arc.e(2,3)(superpull);  % left half of upper bowl
filldraw stroke super_arc.e(3,4) & super_arc.e(4,1); % right half of upper bowl
pos5(vair,90); pos6(left_curve,180); pos7(vair,270); pos8(right_curve,360);
bot y7r=-d; rt x8r=hround(w-u); lft x6r=hround(.5w+1.5u);
top y5r=vround(if monospace: .3 else: .5 fi\\ asc_height);
x5=x7=.5[x6,x8]; y6=y8=.5[y5,y7];
filldraw stroke pulled_super_arc.e(5,6)(superpull)
 & pulled_super_arc.e(6,7)(superpull);  % left half of lower bowl
filldraw stroke super_arc.e(7,8) & super_arc.e(8,5); % right half of lower bowl
pickup rule.nib; top y9=h; bot y10=-d;
if hefty: x9=good.x(x5-eps); x10=good.x(x1+eps);
 draw z9--z10;  % diagonal
else: rt x9=hround(w-2.5u); lft x10=hround 2.5u; draw z9--z10;  % diagonal
 pickup fine.nib; pos9(rule_thickness,angle(z9-z10)+90);
 pos11(vair,angle(z1r-z4r)-90); pos12(vair,angle(z9-z10)+90);
 path p; p=super_arc.r(1,4); z11r=point 2/3 of p; z12r=z9r;
 filldraw stroke z11e{direction 2/3 of p}...{z9-z10}z12e; fi  % link
penlabels(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12); endchar;
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Do you know some way to see the characters which `mf cmr10` generates from the sources and displays on the screen, one by one instead of a batch mode?

Comment: this is indeed the code for the percent sign.  however, a warning ... some settings are not explicit, but carried over from previous definitions in the file.  this was demonstrated a long time ago by moving around the order of some glyph definitions (i think it was in the main alphabet file, not this one), resulting in an error with some value being undefined.  (it was judged by knuth to *not* be a bug.)  so be careful.

Comment: @Ho1 `mf '\mode=proof;input cmr10'` (with some other setting, I guess, but I don't have the Metafontbook at hand).